# JQuery :contains can't find text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use :contains to find bits of text inside a div and it's working fine except when it encounters documents that include "&nbsp" or "'".

Strangely enough, I can use :contains even for text that contains "&amp", but not for the other cases.

Here's my attempt, also at https://jsfiddle.net/sesyj5kd/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="well">
        <div id="dText" style="background: white; height: 90%; overflow-y:auto;" ></div>
     </div>    
    </div>   
  </div>  
</div>
```

Script:

```
var str1 = "<html><head></head><body><p>This is the doc's first sentence</p><div>not the first sentence, but it's in a div & all </div>    </body></html>";

$("#dText").html( str1 );

console.log( $("#dText").html() ); 
console.log( $("*:contains('the doc's first')") );
console.log( $("*:contains('in a div & all')") );
```

The second :contains finds the specified text, but the first doesn't, even if I search for "doc\'s"; is it necessary/possible to escape characters like &nbsp or something of the sort?

**The main problem** I'm facing is that div.html(htmlString) displays the content correctly, but looking at console.log(div.html()) I can see a lot of &nbsp (even though these are not in the HTML string) which prevent :contains from working properly on any multiword query when the target text has an &nbsp between words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line:

```
console.log( $("*:contains('the doc's first')") );
```

to:

```
console.log('Second Log: ' +   $("*:contains(\"the doc's first\")").length );
                                             ^^               ^^
```

```js
var str1 = "<html><head></head><body><p>This is the doc's first sentence</p><div>not the first sentence, but it's in a div & all </div>    </body></html>";

$("#dText").html(str1);

console.log('First Log: ' + $("#dText").html());
console.log('Second Log: ' + $("*:contains(\"the doc's first\")").length);
console.log('Third Log: ' + $("*:contains('in a div & all')").length);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="well">
                <div id="dText" style="background: white; height: 90%; overflow-y:auto;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are tring to console log a collection of elements which constains the searched string. You should target an info about it... Like its `class`.

I added classes to your injected string.

Then, like said, it is a collection. A simple `console.log()` like you do will output the first found element... Which would probably be the `body` or the `html`. You have to target the last found element, the "closest" one from the searched string.

And finally, you have to escape the quote in the search string.

Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/6eaLq77n/)... Look at the console.

```
var str1 = "<p class='myP'>This is the doc's first sentence</p><div class='myDiv'>not the first sentence, but it's in a div & all </div>";

$("#dText").html( str1 );
console.log("String: "+ $("#dText").html() ); 

var test1 = $("*:contains('the doc\\'s first')");
var test2 = $("*:contains('in a div & all')");


// Get the last element found containing the string.
console.log("1: "+test1.last().attr("class"));
console.log("2: "+test2.last().attr("class"));
```

Comment: Actually, the "simple console.log()" prints (in FF Dev Tools) the chain of elements and the last element on the chain is clearly identifiable and contains the text I'm searching for.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with this... Is there something to do to improve the answer?